# Project Management - forking from SVN main to Git as a fork with ability to rebase the svn as required

Tags: git, svn, version-control, project, smartgit

I wish to fork a project that is currently managed via SVN to Git.
The SVN repo is svn.openvpms.org/openvpms
Under this are around 8 sub-projects each of which have trunk/branch/tag directories.
When I work in my IDE I actually check each out via svn separately but under a specific directory structure 
eg
If this is how SVN shows the projects
Openvpms

- svn.openvpms.org

  - openvpms

    - Project 1 (eg openvpms) (this would be the parent project)

      - branch
      - trunk
      - tag
    - Project 2 (eg openvpms-archetype) (the parent would depend on this)

      - branch
      - trunk
      - tag

when I check them out locally 
I will check out the trunk to

- MainDir

  - Project 1 (project 1 trunk)

    - src
  - Project 2  (project 2 trunk)

    - src

What I would like to do is for fork the whole setup to git, using git-svn but maintain the branchs and tags from SVn for each project.

I could create a Git repo for each project and clone each one which might be my only option, the slight concern I have here is that it would lose the obvious directory structure that exists on the svn repo.

Is there any other way to clone the entire svn repo into a single git repo and maintain the trunk/branch/tags of each subproject?

I recongnize the fact that there is a project management SE site now, but this question really pertains to the usage of git-svn to clone multiple projects each with a tag/branch/trunk structure.

When I issue

```bash
 git svn clone "svn://svn.openvpms.org/openvpms/openvpms" \
 "C:\Users\mydirectory\OPENVPMS-Git LOCAL REPO\openvpms" \
 -T trunk -b branches -t tags
```

what acctually happens straight away is

> Initialized empty Git repository in `c:/Users/mydirectory/GIT_LOCAL_REPO/openvpms/.git/`
>   Using higher level of URL: `svn://svn.openvpms.org/openvpms/openvpms => svn://svn.openvpms.org/openvpms`

So it seems git-svn goes straight back up to the parent anyway...I am just not sure how it will find all the branches and tags.

I am currently trying to use SmartGit's interface to clone the entire repo from the base url `svn://svn.openvpms.org/openvpms`...it seems to take days and has locked up twice requiring a restart.

Comment: Ok so it seems using git-svn on each svn project will work creating 8 or so git repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well I think I finally sorted this one in the end it comes down to using git svn 
Firstly I added each svn project as a remote in git by editing the .git/config file. I gave them each a different remote name and alias.

```
/...
[svn-remote "parent"]
     url = svn://example.com/rootproject
    fetch = rootproject/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = rootproject/branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    tags = rootproject/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
[svn-remote "subproject1"]
    url = svn://localhost/rootproject
    fetch = subproject1/trunk:refs/remotes/subproject1/trunk
    branches = subproject1/branches/*:refs/remotes/subproject1/*
    tags = subproject1/tags/*:refs/remotes/subproject1/tags/*
[svn-remote "subproject2"]
    url = svn://localhost/rootproject
    fetch = subproject2/trunk:refs/remotes/subproject2/trunk
    branches = subproject2/branches/*:refs/remotes/subproject2/*
    tags = subproject2/tags/*:refs/remotes/subproject2/tags/*
[svn-remote "subproject3"]
    url = svn://localhost/openvpms
    fetch = subproject3/trunk:refs/remotes/subproject3/trunk
    branches = subproject3/branches/*:refs/remotes/subproject3/*
    tags = subproject3/tags/*:refs/remotes/subproject3/tags/*
    ..../
```

etc

then I ran

```
git svn fetch --all
```

This checked out each project into the root of the git repo
Now to restructure
I checked out

```
git checkout origin/trunk
```

then ran for each sub project

```
git merge -s ours --no-commit subproject1/master <2>
git read-tree --prefix=subproject1/ -u subproject1/master <3>
git commit -m "Merge subproject1 as our subdirectory" <4>
```

I now had a project that looked like

```
ParentProject
|-src
|-parentpom.xml
|-subproject1
|    |-src
|    |-pom.xml
|-subproject2
|    |-src
|    |-pom.xml
|-subproject3
|    |-src
|    |-pom.xml
```

etc

Now I think I can still run

```
git fetch --all
```

then run

```
git pull -s subtree subproject1 trunk
```

to update and pull changes from the base svn repos..however given this represents a move to stay with git while keeping all the svn history this should work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You **must** to read [git-svn Man Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) fully and carefully

> it seems git-svn goes straight back up to the parent anyway

Just discover and try `--no-minimize-url` option for `git init`

> I could create a Git repo for each project and clone each one which might be my only option

It *seems* Git can track many SVN-repositories in single Git repository (I'm not experienced Git-boy, just tried RTFM slightly deeply), but it will require handwork (and, surprise, pure CLI).

- In "Configuration" section of [git-svn man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) I saw `[svn-remote "project-a"]` sample with glob patterns in branches|tags definition (after clone of first svn-remote you can (?) add the rest remotes my hand)
- ["Practical tips for using Git with large Subversion repositories"](http://www.janosgyerik.com/practical-tips-for-using-git-with-large-subversion-repositories/) in "Getting other Subversion branches" suggests using for than one fetch definitions inside one svn-remote with different `RELPATH` (thus - you can try to get 1 svn-remote with many `fetch` inside for trunk/branches/tags of real SVN-projects inside SVN-repo)